# Sum object values

Tags: javascript, object, reduce

I'm trying to sum the values from the key "value" in the object data.
Googled alot but cant figure this out.
My guess is that i'm not retrieving the values from localStorage.
EDIT: And i want to save the summed values to localStorage...

```js
var storage = localStorage.getItem("Bills");
if (storage !== null) {
  var data = JSON.parse(storage);
  loadData(data);
  var id = data.length;
} else {
  id = 0;
  data = [];
};

function loadData(array) {
  array.forEach(function(bill) {
    newItem(bill.name, bill.value, bill.id, bill.payed);
  });
};

function addBill() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
  var bill = document.getElementById("billName").value;
  var billVal = document.getElementById("billValue").value;
  newItem(bill, billVal, id, false);
  data.push({
    name: bill,
    value: billVal,
    id: id,
    payed: false
  });
  billsTotals.innerHTML = Object.values(data).reduce((t, { value }) => t + value, 0); // ?????
  localStorage.setItem("Bills", JSON.stringify(data));
};

function newItem(name, value, id, payed) {
  if (payed == true) {
    return;
  }
  
  var ul = document.getElementById("list");
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name + " " + value + "kr"));
  li.setAttribute("id", id);
  ul.appendChild(li);
  bill = document.getElementById("billName").value = "";
  billVal = document.getElementById("billValue").value = "";
};
```

i'v tried to add .values before reduce but nothing works:

```
billsTotals.innerHTML = Object.values(data.value).reduce((t, {value}) => t + value, 0); // ?????
```

Comment: We need more info/code to help with this.
Could you give a full example with a Code Snippet? 
Or at least tell us what `newItem` does, and what `data` looks like and how it is formatted/added to.

Comment: Your reduce function works right if data is initialized correctly : https://jsfiddle.net/qxhtLyob/1/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your data variable. But the data variable is an array then you could do something like this.

```
data.reduce((total,{value})=>{
return total +value
},0)
```

Comment: This is ok too, the OP just uses a short-writing for an one-liner.

Comment: this just adds the values after another.. not summing them. :(